# Close and Run PHP file Again (PHP-CLI)

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I have one socket connection based PHP file which I am running through command line like

```
php myfile.php
```

Its keep running 24 X 7. Sometime if there some issue, its getting exit with error so I want exit and open that file automatically again. My While function in which above error coming is like below

```
while (1) {
    try {
        $w->pollMessage();
        if (time() - $starttime > 180) {
            echo "refresh";
            newNumbers();
            $starttime = time();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        // error coming here and I want reload (run same file again) here.
    }
    if (!$w->isConnected()) {
        echo "disconnected";
        connectwa();
    }
}
$w->disconnect();
?>
```

I don't know which method I should use for reload or run same file again via command line automatically. Let me know if someone can help me for do it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nohup to catch the hangup signal. Redirect the stdout, stderr and stdin and use & to start the new process in the background.
By doing this the new process is safely detached and the current process can cleanly exit.

```
$command = 'nohup php myfile.php > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt < /dev/null &';
system($command);
exit;
```

Instead of redirecting to a file and overwriting the file everytime you can also append a file by using two > signs.

```
$command = 'nohup php myfile.php >> stdout.txt 2>> stderr.txt < /dev/null &';
```

This will capture all output in stdout.txt en stderr.txt.

In the following sample code this is demonstrated. The file myfile.php will be started again and the original process can safely die.

```
<?php

$timescalled = isset($argv[1]) ? $argv[1] : 0;

while (1) {
    try {
        $rand_between_0_and_1 = mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax();
        if ($rand_between_0_and_1 < 0.001) throw new Exception();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        fwrite(STDERR, "hello stderr\n");
        fwrite(STDOUT, "hello stdout\n");
        $command = 'nohup php myfile.php ' . ++$timescalled . ' >> stdout.txt 2>> stderr.txt < /dev/null &';
        system($command);
        exit;
    }
}
```

The output can be read from stdout.txt and stdout.txt. By using:

```
tail -f output.txt &
```

content added to output.txt is automatically shown in the terminal.
You now almost got your command output back .

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. Can I know it will reload my php file in same command line? Thanks

Comment: @SunilJain What do you mean by 'same command line'? It will start the same command again and it will run just like your original command. It is however detached from the terminal. So you won't see output in the terminal.

Comment: I want see same out put. I am looking for stop current file and run again it. Thanks